# Neighborhood with chronic internet outages ISP won't fix

Tags: contract-law

My neighbors and I have had problems with internet service intermittently for years.  Since I was at home full time, I decided to get serious about making them fix it.  I've been through every aspect of the customer service apparatus, contacted every relevant State and Federal agency, and still I cannot get them to fix the real problem.  At any point do my neighbors and I have a legal remedy?  There is only one high speed provider here (FL US), if it matters.
Thank you.
[Internet Down Log.txt](https://pastebin.com/ZDbnM3yB)

Comment: The account holder (you or the neighbor) may sue the ISP for breach of contract and/or claims sounding in *unfair & deceptive practices*. It seems you would request *injunctive relief* to the effect of making the ISP improve the service to a level that is acceptable as per your contract. Other than that, your question is too broad to give a more useful answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Fla. Stat. 364.011](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0300-0399/0364/0364.html), broadband services in Florida are not subject to state regulation, there are no statutory / regulatory standards for network downtime. So you would have to see what guarantees you were given in your contract – mine makes no enforceable promises, it just simply say they will try hard and I can call them to report problems. If they make a concrete claim like "we promise that internet service will be not be unavailable for more than 10% of the time per 24 hours for more than 2 consecutive days", then they may have breached their contract. Without a specific promise, you can't sue them for not providing the service that you want.